# How to go from a List[F[String]] to F[List[String]] using Scala and Cats?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm new to Cats and I don't know how to overcome this situation. In the code bellow:

```
class Example[F[_]] {
  import cats._
  import cats.data._
  import cats.syntax.all._

  def saveAll(list: List[String])(implicit M: Monad[F]): F[List[String]] = {
    val result: List[F[String]] =
      list.map(saveOne)
  }

  def saveOne(s: String)(implicit M: Monad[F]): F[String] = s"Saved $s".pure[F]
}
```

How do I transform the `result` variable, in the `saveAll` function, to make sure it matches its expected return type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This kind of transformation is done with the `traverse` operation:

```
class Example[F[_]] {
  import cats._
  import cats.implicits._

  def saveAll(list: List[String])(implicit M: Monad[F]): F[List[String]] = 
    list.traverse(saveOne)

  def saveOne(s: String)(implicit M: Monad[F]): F[String] = 
    s"Saved $s".pure[F]
}
```

As you can see from the `traverse` method signature in `Traverse` typeclass it requires an instance of [`Applicative`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicative.html), not a `Monad`:

```
trait Traverse[F[_]] {
  def traverse[G[_]: Applicative, A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[B]): G[F[B]]
}
```

In cats every type that has a `Monad` also has an `Applicative`, so the `Example` class works even with `Monad`.

But the reverse is not true. Some types only have an `Applicative` instance. The most notable of those is `Validated`. You can read more about the problem with implementing `Monad` for `Validated` in [the cats documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html#of-flatmaps-and-eithers).

So this code will be more general if you request an instance of `Applicative` instead:

```
class Example[F[_]] {
  import cats._
  import cats.implicits._

  def saveAll(list: List[String])(implicit M: Applicative[F]): F[List[String]] = 
    list.traverse(saveOne)

  def saveOne(s: String)(implicit M: Applicative[F]): F[String] = 
    s"Saved $s".pure[F]
}
```